# I don't receive when someone sends me messages through whatsapp broadcast

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Two of my friends have added my phone number in their WhatsApp broadcast. I used to received messages from them till December 3rd. But now I don't received any messages from them. I checked their phone and sent message is showing, but i dont receive. How to fix this error?

Comment: Did you update WhatsApp to the latest version?

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, i did.

Comment: Possible dupe: [WhatsApp cannot receive any broadcasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230735/44325) (not yet answered)